# There exist $2$ numbers out of $12$ the difference of which is divisible by $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

If there is a set of $12$ distinct positive integer numbers, how can we prove that there are two numbers among them the difference of which is divisible by $11$?

Comment: You didn't say distinct...but it doesn't matter.  Just take $\{1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,100,111,122\}$

Comment: @lulu A set is defined to be a collection of distinct objects.

Comment: I gave an example with distinct elements.  All of the numbers in that example are $1$ more than multiples of $11$ so the sum of any two of them is $2$ more than a multiple of $11$, hence not divisible by $11$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. Your explained clearly what I needed to know. If you can put it as a answer that will be more useful.

Comment: @lulu What the answer if we change this question by replacing addition of a pair of numbers with difference of two numbers.

Comment: That one is correct.  I'll add a proof to my post below.

Comment: Take a look at what I posted (especially for the difference case).  Is it clear enough?

Comment: @lulu Thank you. And I have one more question. In the above set of numbers is there any subset of numbers whose sum is divisible by 11?

Comment: Sure, just add up any $11$ of them.

Comment: @lulu if the set is $\{2,13,24,35,46,57,68,90,101,112\}$ , then how can we say there is any subset of numbers whose sum is divisible by 11?

Comment: If you look at my post I show that this is true for any set of $12$ integers (actually, it's true for any set of $11$ integers).  In your example, every integer is of the form $11n+2$.  Therefore, adding any $11$ of them gives a number divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORIGINAL QUESTION: As stated the desired claim is false, as remarked in the comments.

More emphatically, consider the infinite sequence of natural numbers$$A=\{1,12,23,\dots\}$$

(so $A=\{a_n\}$ where $a_n=1+11n$).

Then the sum of any two of these is $2$ more than a multiple of $11$, as $$a_n+a_m=1+11n+1+11m=2+11(n+m)$$

In particular, $a_n+a_m$ is never divisible by $11$.

DIFFERENCE:  if instead we asked about the difference, then the claim is true.  To see that suppose we had a collection of $12$ integers $S=\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{12}$.  These need not be distinct and they need not be positive.  We note that there are only $11$ possible remainders resulting from division by $11$...thus, by the Pigeonhole Principle, at least $2$ of the $s_i$ must have the same remainder.  But then the difference of those two elements is divisible by $11$.

SUBSET VARIANT:  If instead of asking for the sum of "two" elements we allowed for the sum over any non-empty subset then the desired claim is true for any collection of $12$ integers.  To see that, let $S=\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{12}$ be our collection.  Consider the nested sums $$S(k)=s_1+\dots+s_k$$ for $k\in \{1,\dots, 12\}$

There are $12$ of these nested sums so at least  two of these have to leave the same remainder on division by $11$.  But if $S(m)$ and $S(n)$ have the same remainder, with $m>n$, we must have $$11|s_{n+1}+\dots+s_m$$

Comment: **SUBSET VARIANT:** If the set is $\{2,13,24,35,46,57,68,90,101,112\}$ , then how can we say there is any subset of numbers whose sum is divisible by 11?

Comment: Follow the procedure I describe...in this case it shows that $13+14+\dots+112$ is divisible by $11$.  Actually, the sum of any $11$ of those numbers is divisible by $11$.

Comment: Yes. Now I got it clearly.